# user_profile_form doesn't show profile2 information

Tags: forms, users

I'm trying to modify the user_profile_form, but it isn't working. My regular user edit information shows up, but not my profile2 information.

```
    function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'conduit') . '/js/jvectormap.min.js'; // You should place jvectormap js files into MYMODULE/js folder
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'conduit') . '/js/jquery-jvectormap-mi-counties.js'; // This is US counties generated file (see #1).
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'conduit') . '/js/county-select.js';
    $form['mi_container'] = array(
        '#type' => "container",
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(// action to take.
                'select[name="profile_main[field_states][und]"]' => array('value' => 187),
            ),
        ),
    );
    $form['mi_container']['micounties_markup'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<div id="micounties" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>', // Define own width and height.
    );

  }
}
```

Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

You've implemented [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), which only fires for a single form (user_register_form in this case).

If you want to catch multiple forms in a single function, you need [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that. Thank you. Is there anyway to delete a question?

Comment: Looks like you found it ;)

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that even with the form alter changed, is that it's still not showing me my profile2 information, so I'm going to undelete the question and change it.

Comment: One thing I'm thinking it might be caused by is module weight, will test.

Comment: It seems like it may be related to this. I'll probably give you the answer as you set me on the right path.